# Saving an uiimageview to tableview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I dont think im doing this correctly. I have this drawing app and once I make a drawing in my UIImageView I want to press the save button and save an image of the drawing in the table view. I have this code but it doesn't save the drawing to the tableview when I press save. Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong because I cant figure it out. Thank you!

```
//ViewController
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

var myImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()



self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false



UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()


//Saving Image Here

myImages.append(image)
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image.png").path!
data?.writeToFile(fileURL, atomically: true)
}



//MasterViewController--------------------------------------------------



override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    return 1
}



 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return myImages.count
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
    imageView.image = myImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.addSubview(imageView)
    return cell
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        }
    }



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40 //Some number to fit the image
}




override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
```

Comment: What is `myImages` in `saveButton`: `var myImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()`

Comment: Am I supposed to save it to my imageview instead of declaring it like that? Because I have an @IBOutlet for the UIImageview I use for the drawing.

Comment: I don't know why you have to write this line `var myImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()`. Because I think you have a var `myImages` somewhere. How about you remove that line. And what happen?

Comment: well the line for myImages.append(image) I get an error saying use of unresolved identifier myImages.

Comment: Where did you init the var `myImages` in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`?

Comment: var myImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage]() I put this in the MasterViewController scene and used it here   imageView.image = myImages[indexPath.row]

Comment: In `ViewController` you should replace this line `var myImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()` somewhere, not in `saveButton(sender: AnyObject)`. Try to create a property `myImages` in `ViewController`, and init it `var myImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()`` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93435/discussion-between-coding22-and-anhtu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the table in `saveButton` after model is updated something like this `self.tableView.reloadData()` for table view to pick the latest data and render it.

As a side note, instead of storing `UIImage` in array, you should save their local path in file system in the array and load them from path in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.